# Azure Cloud Shell Initiate Fail

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azureportal

Getting 'Storage Creation Failed'.As per screenshot,please advise:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to open `Show advanced settings` and select the correct configuration.

[image]

[image]

If you still can't solve your problem after configuration, maybe you can seek help from Microsoft official technical support, which does not cost any money.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Manually input of the configuration solved it. Initially i did not have to input that though.

Answer (score 1):

Error message says resource provider in your subscription is not enabled. Go to `Azure portal > Subcriptions > Resource provider > Microsoft.Storage > Register` as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, although I can confirm that Microsoft.Storage is registered.That is not the cause of the problem.